# Can't get to work Masonry and Bootstrap together

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

My site has a basic structure that's something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row masonry-container">
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="panel">
       Panel content here.
      </div>
    </div>
 <!-- I have 15 col-md-4 and panel before closing my row and container -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Each panel has some links inside that get's from a Wordpress while loop. Because of that, all my panels have different heights, and I want to use a Masonry style grid so I can fit them all in an elegant way.

My script for Masonry is this:

```
<script>
$('.masonry-container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item', 
  columnWidth: '.panel',
  percentPosition: true
});
</script>
```

This is the first time that I try to use a masonry grid, and it is not working, but I don't have any idea of what the problem may be.

**EDIT**

This is a screen of the website I'm working. As you may see, the grids are getting in position as if Masonry isn't there, and just as Bootstrap default grid.
[Screen of my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deEdC.jpg)

Comment: Why do you use `col-md-4` classes? And what means `columntWidth: `'.panel'`?

Comment: @makshh `col-md-4` is one of the bootstrap grid css classes https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ and I'm guessing the `columnWidth: '.panel'` is part of Masonry.

Comment: I'm using `col-md-4` to get that bootsrap column responsive size (so I will have 3 columns in desktop, and stackable content on other devices). I'm using `columnWidth: .pane` to get the width of my panel as Masonry Js request. Sould I do it in a different way?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what you said.

Comment: Can you add some detail to how it is not working in your question? What exactly is not working? How is it not working? Things like that.

Comment: Hi Zack, I've just edited the main post and uploaded a screen of the website I'm working. As you may see, the grid is just as if there isn't any Masonry script working, and Just as Bootstrap defalt grid. [This is a link to the live website](http://www.gador.com.ar/mvp/)

Comment: I'm getting javascript errors on your page saying `Object doesn't support property or method 'masonry'`, so I think it may just be not including the scripts in the correct order that is causing issues.

Comment: Specifically, your script that calls masonry is on line 638, and the masonry script itself isn't included until line 661. You might be able to wrap the masonry call inside of a jQuery self-invoking function to get it to work if you can't change where the script is included. `$(function() { /* code here */ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your *Script para Masonry* to be:

```
$(function(){
  $('.masonry-container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item', 
    columnWidth: '.panel',
    percentPosition: true
  });
});
```

Your page is getting errors like `Object doesn't support property or method 'masonry'`, so you need to delay executing the script until the page is finished loading. This is an example of the shorthand version of `$(document).ready()` in jQuery as shown here https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Hi Zack, I've just moved my Jquery to the footer file of my WP and now it's working as it should! Thank you very much for noticing what the problem is and for the help! I will also read the link you share with me. Regards!

Comment: One thing I'm noticing now is when the viewport is small or xs, there are large gaps between the stacked panels. Not sure what is causing that.

Comment: @GermánGallo it seems like it is only happening when I resize the viewport from md or large down to sm or xs, the animation happens and there are large gaps between the panels. If I load the page initially as sm or xs, then there are no gaps.

Comment: Adding `col-xs-12` may fix that --> `<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 item">`

Comment: Hi Zack and vanburen. Just as you said, there was a problem when resizing the viewport. I've done what vanburen says and now everything is working perfect :) Thank you both of you!